# How to put an updating variable of a blocking function into asynchronous data stream of ReactiveX

Tags: asynchronous, observable, reactive-programming, observer-pattern, reactivex

I'm trying to send an int variable which is continuously updated in a for loop. Inside the for loop, data is published to an observable. Since the variable is incremented in a blocking call, and I want to fetch this value in my reactiveX subscription method. Note: I don't want to add this variable to my async data stream (i.e., without sending this value with publisher.onNext() method).

after incrementing the int variable and publishing to observable in each iteration of for loop, I call wait() on an object. In the subscription consumption, I fetch the value of variable and then notify() the same object. I get the exception 'Async loop interrupted'

```
public int var=0;

main(String[] args) {
    for loop {
        variable++;
        publisher.onNext(args[0]);
        //call wait on a thread to make sure current value of 'var' 
        //is picked in the getSubscriber() method
        wait(); 
    }
}

public Subscriber<T> getSubscriber() {
    return new Subscriber<Inference>() {
            @Override public void onCompleted() {}
            @Override public void onError(Throwable e) { 
               e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            @Override public void onNext(Inference infer) {
                //do something

                sysout(var);
                //call notify on the thread to resume control in for 
                //loop
                notify();
            }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have to call the `wait()` and `notify()` in `synchronized` blocks and it works.